# Linked List Query

Tags: c, linked-list

Essentially the problem is, that I want such input:

```
Hello
World
.
```

To Be outputted in reverse word order:

```
World
Hello
```

Yet my code seems to output

```
orldello
```

Missing the `\n` and the first letters of each word, and I'm at a brick wall with knowing what to do!

This is what I have tried so far:

```
typedef struct List {
  char c;
  struct List *next;
} List;

typedef struct {
  List *head;
  List *tail;
} FullList;

List* InsertList(int hd, List* t1) {
  List *t = (List*)calloc(1,sizeof(List));
  t->c = hd; 
  t->next = t1;
  return t;
}

FullList addToStart(FullList c1, char element) {
  if (c1.head == NULL) {
    c1.head = c1.tail = InsertList(element, NULL);
  } else {
    c1.head = InsertList(element, c1.head);
  }
  return c1;
}

int main(void) {
  FullList InOrder;
  FullList Reverse;
  InOrder.head = NULL;
  Reverse.head = NULL;
  char c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != '.') {

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
      InOrder = addToStart(InOrder,c);
    }

    while ((InOrder.head) != NULL ) {
      Reverse = addToStart(Reverse, InOrder.head->c);
      InOrder.head = InOrder.head->next;
    }     
  }

  while(Reverse.head != NULL) {
    printf("%c", Reverse.head->c);
    Reverse.head = Reverse.head->next;
  }
  return 0;           
}
```

Comment: Well, to start with, you're never adding the \n to the list...

Comment: Hmm, but the problem is, I need to add the words to the Reverse List one by one, so that they come out in the reverse order, and I cant think of another termination condition.

Comment: Then use a do {} while loop so you check for \n AFTER adding the char to the list, thus jumping out of the loop only after a \n has been added.

Comment: Now I appear to get WorldHello printed out, still missing one \n, although its fixed the issue with the missing first characters.

Comment: Any clues Nick, still can't seem to get this working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Final Linked Lists Query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279079/final-linked-lists-query)

Answer (score 0):

You don't store the newlines because of this:

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
```

The loop body is repeated as long as the read character is not newline. When it is newline, the code in the loop is *not* executed.

The first character of each line is dropped because you do this:

```
while((c = getchar()) != '.') {
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
```

You read a character, *do nothing with it*, read a character again, and then append it to the list. Just get rid of the inner loop and its should work fine.

EDIT:
I've misunderstood the question. If you want to reverse the order of the lines, don't add each character as an element to the list. Change the type of list elements from `char` to `char*` and store each line as an element:

```
char buff[500];
fgets(buff, 500, stdin);
char *new_element = strdup(buff);
/* Add new_element to the list */
```

Comment: I cant remove the inner loop, otherwise it doesnt reverse my input.

Comment: I input Hello\nWorld\n. It stores it in my list n\dlorWn\olleH. Therefore that inner loop was there to insure it flipped my input round word by word, and printed it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish. You always append to the "middle" of the list, and if you find a newline you set the middle of the list to the head pointer.

```
FullList l;
Lust* ins = l.head = insertList(NULL,0); // sentinel
while ((c = getchar()) != '.') {
  ins = ins->next = insertList(ins->next,c);
  if (c == '\n') {
    ins = l.head;
  }
}
ins = l.head;
free(l.head);
l.head = ins;
```

Note that the tail pointer is not used and also never set to a correct value.